# Eclpise ingo error:-'The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files'

Tags: java, eclipse

this Error Appear when i extend exception class in eclipse indigo, but it works properly in net-beans 8.2

```
package com;// error 


public class ex extends Exception{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ex(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are missing the required import statements...

Comment: You are comparing the behavior of the current version of Netbeans to a 5+ year old version of Eclipse. Try it with the current Eclipse.

Comment: Is this the only class in your project/workspace?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the posted code. 
Eclipse Indigo should also work fine for the code you have posted above. Possibly something else in the package/Project in same workspace which is giving that error ?